# How to draw 2d above 3d scene?

Tags: opengl, 2d, 3d, projection, pipeline

I have an OpenGL(3.3)+GLEW application. 
I want to draw a black vertical rectangle at the left side of the window for writing some information on it, like fps (I use GLEW function for drawing text).

I have a common pipeline, like this:

```
 m_transformation = PersProjTrans * CameraRotateTrans *
           CameraTranslationTrans * TranslationTrans * 
           RotateTrans * ScaleTrans;
```

I know how it works, but I can't figure out how to draw a projection of the rectangle on the window, like 2d.

I would be glad to any advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [*Orthographic projection*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_projection) matrix to transform your vertexes. Then you can simply provide your triangle verts in terms of screen pixels, e.g.: a vertex at (0,0), one at (10, 0) and one at (5, 10).

[Here's another reference](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html) of OpenGL matrices, with a lot of maths. Make sure to do a search for "OpenGL orthographic projection" and "2D drawing with OpenGL" and you should find a lot of useful information also.

I should also note that to overlay 2D over 3D, you'll have to disable depth testing before drawing the 2D parts. I.e.: `glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);`.